# Display image every 10 posts starting after 5th post

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I got a while loop in WordPress and want to add an image after every 10th post. Only I want to start this after the 5th post to happen.

I tried something like this but not able to tweak it so it does as I discribed above.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
if($i % 5 == 0) 
    echo '<img src="/image.gif">';
    ++$i; 
?>
```

How can I manage to get it to start after post 5 and after that every 10th post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the counter at 6

```
<?php 
    $i = 6;  // start i at 6

    while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
        if($i % 10 == 0) 
            echo '<img src="/image.gif">';
        ++$i; 
    }
?>
```

A mocked up example

```
<?php 
    $i = 6;  // start i at 6

    while ( $i < 31 ) {
        if($i % 10 == 0) { 
            echo "info $i" . PHP_EOL;
            echo '<img src="/image.gif">' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo "info $i" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        ++$i; 
    }
?>
```

Results

```
info 6
info 7
info 8
info 9
info 10
<img src="/image.gif">
info 11
info 12
info 13
info 14
info 15
info 16
info 17
info 18
info 19
info 20
<img src="/image.gif">
info 21
info 22
info 23
info 24
info 25
info 26
info 27
info 28
info 29
info 30
<img src="/image.gif">
```

Comment: Isn't the 5th post in the array 4? Is `$i` 0 to start?

Comment: As I read it, shouldn't `$i` end in 4 for each iteration assuming post 5 has an `$i` of 4?

Comment: @JayBlanchard You definitely made me look again. So I mocked up an example as I dont have WP. And it look like 6 is the magic number

Comment: The OP hasn't filled us in, but assuming `$i` starts at 0 he wants to skip post 4, then every 10 after that, all numbers ending in 4. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I get the question its... Show 5 posts then an advert, then show 10 posts and show an advert from then on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
$i++;
if($i % 10 == 0 and $i > 5) 
    echo '<img src="/image.gif">';
?>
```

It will check if the post number is divided by 10 without a remainder and if the post number is larger than 5.

I have also moved your iterator before the if statement because otherwise the post number will start at 0 and will output the first image on post number 6 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$i` is originally 0, the fifth post would have an `$i` of 4. Therefore we skip 4 (the fifth post), then get every 10 after (ending in 4):

```
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    if(4 < $i) 
        if(4 == substr($i, -1)) 
            echo '<img data-count="'.$i.'" src="/image.gif">'."\n";                
    $i++;
```

Result:

```
<img data-count="14" src="/image.gif">
<img data-count="24" src="/image.gif">
<img data-count="34" src="/image.gif">
```

Here is the code I used to test with:

```
$arr = array_fill(0, 40, 'pic');

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    if(4 < $i) 
        if(4 == substr($i, -1)) 
            echo '<img data-count="'.$i.'" src="/image.gif">'."\n";
```

Comment: I think the difference is you are using an array 0 based, but the OP seemed to me to be using a counter anything based so I assumed 1 as the `++` is after the doiings i started at 6

Comment: Yeah @RiggsFolly, hard to know without the OP commenting on where he starts.

Comment: I dont think it matters where he starts when he uses a counter to control the switching#